# conditionally remove rows that are not NA

Tags: r

I need to remove the rows that do not have NA values in the final two columns. Any ideas?

```
# A tibble: 640 x 4
   `7 (very included)` `7 (very included)__1` X__1              X__2             
   <chr>               <chr>                  <chr>             <chr>            
 1 NA                  NA                     NA                NA               
 2 7 (very included)   5                      NA                NA               
 3 NA                  NA                     NA                NA               
 4 7 (very included)   7 (very included)      7 (very included) 7 (very included)
 5 NA                  NA                     NA                NA               
 6 NA                  NA                     NA                NA               
 7 NA                  NA                     NA                NA               
 8 5                   4                      NA                NA               
 9 NA                  NA                     NA                NA               
10 7 (very included)   7 (very included)      7 (very included) NA               
# ... with 630 more rows
```

Comment: Sorry, that table did not paste very  well. But hopefully the question is still clear. I have tried: 

OtherIncluded <- OtherIncluded[!(OtherIncluded$X__1! = "NA" & OtherIncluded$X__2! = "NA") ,] 

But this was unsuccessful.

Comment: Please read `?NA` and then use `is.na` to identify missing values. They are not identical with a "NA" string.

Comment: If you want to paste reproducible data, use `dput`. To see an example, try `dput(mtcars)` in R.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe object is `df`, you can filter as below:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(!is.na(`X__1`) & !is.na(`X__2`))
```

Or

```
df[!is.na(df$`X__1`) & !is.na(df$`X__2`), ]
```